# Помогите Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Нужна помощь, нужно сделать чтобы кнопка контакт выводилась после нажатия на 'click to start', срочно помогите.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Label

root = Tk()

root.geometry('700x500')
root.resizable(height= False, width= False)
root.title('артем гей')
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.9)
root ['bg'] = 'black'


main_label = Label(root, text = 'Main menu',
                   font = 'Consolas',
                   fg = 'white',
                   bg = 'black')

thx_label = Label(root,text = 'Thx f0r D0wl0and',
                  font = 'Consolas',
                  fg = 'white',
                  bg ='black')

def com():
    destroy_object = [thx_label, main_label,btn1]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()


btn1 = Button(root,text = 'click to start',
              fg = 'white',
              bg = 'black',
              font = 'Consolas',
              relief= 'solid',
              command= com)



btn2 = Button(root, text = 'contact',
              fg = 'white',
              bg = 'black',
              font = 'Consolas',
              relief= 'solid',
              )



btn2.place(y = 230, x =270)
btn1.place(y = 200 , x = 270)
main_label.pack()
thx_label.place(y = 50, x = 270)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

добавьте в конце btn2 как показано ниже

```
def com():
    destroy_object = [thx_label, main_label,btn1,btn2]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()
```